# Inline code in R Markdown is not executed

Tags: r, r-markdown, inline-code

I have a r chunk in my markdown document and would like to refer to it via inline code in my text. However, when I want to knit the file, I get an error and the markdown document stops.

```
data <- as.data.frame(data)
describe(data[,"age"])

hist(as.numeric(data[,"age"]))

mean_age <- mean(data$age)

data$gender <- factor(data$gender, levels = 1:4, labels = c("Female","Male", "Prefer not to answer", "Another gender"))
summary(data[,"gender"]) # table(data$gender)
```

Here's the inline code:

The mean age of the participants was `r mean_age`. Lorem ipsum etc.

The error ist:

Quitting from lines 168-177 (Seminar_Report.Rmd)
Fehler in data$age : Objekt des Typs 'closure' ist nicht indizierbar
Ruft auf:  ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> mean
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In do_once((if (is_R_CMD_check()) stop else warning)("The function xfun::isFALSE() will be deprecated in the future. Please ",  :
The function xfun::isFALSE() will be deprecated in the future. Please consider using base::isFALSE(x) or identical(x, FALSE) instead.

The data is referencing to a sample df where age is one column with natural numbers.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: which package does `describe` come from?

Comment: We can not reproduce the error with the given information. Please include in your answer: * all packages loaded upstream; necessary code to reproduce "data"; *definition of the function "describe"; * the full code chunk where "mean_age" is defined; * the error message

Comment: the lines that cause it to halt are `\`r hist(as.numeric(data[,"age"]))\`` and `\`r describe(data[,"age"])\``, presumably because they are wanting to insert a very large thing (a plot and a table respectively) inline

Comment: @GuedesBF the following works as sample data (created by me) : `data <- data.frame(
  age = c(25, 30, 28, 35, 42, 32, 37, 29, 31, 26),
  gender = c(2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3)
)`

Comment: @Mark, this toy data may not represent the actual data and could fail to reproduce the errors. I still think we should wait for proper example data from the OP.

Comment: @GuedesBF I think so too, I was just trying to be helpful 

Comment: Yes, I know, but bad questions can only get help so much help.